# Lists in lists and for loops

Tags: python, list, nested

If I have lists with x lists and and for example

```
[[(1,2),(1,4)],[(7,5),(5,4)]]
```

How do I get another list that takes the first numbers of all the tuples in the lists and puts them in a list, and then takes the second numbers of all the tuples in the lists and puts them in a second list.how should I get that with 3 for loop

Expected output for the sample:

```
[(1,1),(7,5)],[(2,4),(5,4)]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) For more tips, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's not clear at all what this sentence _"If I have lists with x lists and rows x and columns x for example"_ means?

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [[(1,2),(1,4)],[(7,5),(5,4)]]

result = list()
fIndexesList = list() #first items
sIndexesList = list() #second items

for item in L:
   
    fIndexesTuple = list()
    sIndexesTuple = list()
   
    for innerItem in item:
     fIndexesTuple.append(innerItem[0])
     sIndexesTuple.append(innerItem[1])
        
    else:     
     fIndexesList.append(tuple(fIndexesTuple))      
     sIndexesList.append(tuple(sIndexesTuple))
        
else:
    result.append(fIndexesList)
    result.append(sIndexesList)
print(result)
```

This should work
By the way ,You can use the loop inside a function

Comment: If I have a list With x lists and x rows and x columns with same question

Comment: make it explicit with an example